# Is it possible to have two default gateway on ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu-14.04

Is it possible to have two default gateway on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You can't define two default gateway. A default gateway is used when your device does not know how to reach the network by specific route or interface.

For example :

Default GW  | Router A

10.1.1.0/24 | Router B

10.2.2.0/24 | Router C

When you want to reach 10.1.1.1 for example the device will use the router B. When you want to reach 10.2.2.1 the device will use the router C. For any other network the device will use the router A.

I suppose your server is directly connected to your local network. Then you just has to define the IP of your server (192.168.225.X) to the interface that side your local network and the default gateway to reach the rest of the world (when a device is directly connected to a specific LAN he know how to reach it).